# Can't install reddit-analysis in Python on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation

I'm trying to install this [reddit-analysis](https://github.com/rhiever/reddit-analysis). I've installed [Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.amd64.msi) on Windows 7 but it's give me [this error:](https://github.com/rhiever/reddit-analysis/issues/46)

```
PS D:\~\reddit-analysis> python .\setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to redditanalysis.egg-info\requires.txt
… 
… 
…
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.46-py3.3.egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 36, in <lambda>
).read(), "setup.py", 'exec'),
File "setup.py", line 22
print "Unit tests have failed!"
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS D:\~\reddit-analysis>
```

I've been [struggling with this for quite some time.](https://github.com/rhiever/reddit-analysis/issues/46#issuecomment-20429387) I have so far, tried installing Python 2.7 (separately (and ran it with proper file path)), update [setuptools to 0.7.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.7.7) (on both 2.7,3.3). But nothing seem to work. Same error.

Something odd (to me<, although this is first time me reading Python code) is that [there is no `print "Unit tests have failed!"` on line 22 ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO96C.png) (as it says in the error above)

Comment: try using python2.7 I meet the some question when i try to install Beautiful Soup.May it will help you

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by running it using Python 3.X. Install Python 2.X, get [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#using-the-installer) and run:

`pip install redditanalysis`

Just make sure that python.exe and pip.exe you are using belong to the 2.X version.